# Examples of Using Async Done with jasmine-given

Tags: javascript, jasmine, bdd

Is anyone using jasmine-given (https://github.com/searls/jasmine-given) for testing asynchronous code?

Apparently, the library supports it. However, the interface for doing that is not documented, and it's not clear from the source code how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

In case OP (or anyone) is still looking here, the README for https://github.com/searls/jasmine-given now includes the documentation:

---

> Following Jasmine 2.0's style for testing asynchronous code, the Given and When statements' functions can take a done parameter, which is a function to call when the asynchronous code completes. Subsequent statements won't be executed until the done completes. E.g.

```
Given (done) -> $.get "/stuff"
                  .success (data) =>
                    @stuff = data
                    done()

When (done) -> $.post "/do", stuff: @stuff
                 .success (data) =>
                    @yay = true
                    done()

Then -> @stuff == "the stuff"
Then -> @yay
```

> The Then and And statement functions can also take a done parameter, if the expectation itself requires asynchronous executation to evalute. For example if you're using Selenium, you might want to check browser state in an expectation:

```
Then (done) -> browser.find '.alert', (el) ->
    expect(el).toBeDefined()
    done()
And (done) -> browser.find '.cancel', (el) ->
    expect(cancel).toBeDefined()
    done()
```